# MSBuild to build Release and QA at same time?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, msbuild, teamcity, build-process

I have a working **msbuild** script in **TeamCity** which builds the **Release** configuration. I also need it to build the "QA" configuration and copy it to the QA folder. Can this be done in one script, or do I need multplie scripts?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
<PropertyGroup>
 <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Release</Configuration>
 <SolutionName>AOP</SolutionName>
 <SolutionFile>AOP.sln</SolutionFile>
 <ProjectName>AOP.Web</ProjectName>
 <ProjectFile>AOP.Web\AOP.Web.csproj</ProjectFile>
</PropertyGroup>

 <Target Name="Build" DependsOnTargets="BuildPackage;CopyOutput" />

<Target Name="BuildPackage">
 <MSBuild Projects="$(SolutionFile)" ContinueOnError="false" Targets="Rebuild" Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration)" />
 <MSBuild Projects="$(ProjectFile)" ContinueOnError="false" Targets="Package" Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration)" />
</Target>

 <Target Name="CopyOutput">
 <ItemGroup>
  <PackagedFiles Include="$(ProjectName)\obj\$(Configuration)\Package\PackageTmp\**\*.*"/>
   </ItemGroup>
   <Copy SourceFiles="@(PackagedFiles)" DestinationFiles="@(PackagedFiles->'c:\devDeploy\AOP\$(Configuration)\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')"/>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its just the value of configuration property which is different for QA, may be you can add another step in the teamcity build and call the same MSBUild script with the QA configuration value. Something like:

```
msbuild.exe YourScript.proj /p:Configuration=DEBUG
```

Alternatively you can try editing your script to something like:

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Release</Configuration>
   <QAConfiguration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">QAConfig</QAConfiguration>
   <SolutionName>AOP</SolutionName>
   <SolutionFile>AOP.sln</SolutionFile>
   <ProjectName>AOP.Web</ProjectName>
   <ProjectFile>AOP.Web\AOP.Web.csproj</ProjectFile>
</PropertyGroup>  

<Target Name="Build" DependsOnTargets="BuildPackage;CopyOutput;BuildQAPackage;CopyQAOutput" />
<Target Name="BuildPackage">
 <MSBuild Projects="$(SolutionFile)" ContinueOnError="false" Targets="Rebuild" Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration)" />
 <MSBuild Projects="$(ProjectFile)" ContinueOnError="false" Targets="Package" Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration)" />
</Target>

<Target Name="CopyOutput">
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackagedFiles Include="$(ProjectName)\obj\$(Configuration)\Package\PackageTmp\**\*.*"/>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Copy SourceFiles="@(PackagedFiles)" DestinationFiles="@(PackagedFiles->'c:\devDeploy\AOP\$(Configuration)\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')"/>
</Target>

<Target Name="BuildQAPackage">
  <MSBuild Projects="$(SolutionFile)" ContinueOnError="false" Targets="Rebuild" Properties="Configuration=$(QAConfiguration)" />
  <MSBuild Projects="$(ProjectFile)" ContinueOnError="false" Targets="Package" Properties="Configuration=$(QAConfiguration)" />
</Target>

<Target Name="CopyQAOutput">
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackagedFiles Include="$(ProjectName)\obj\$(QAConfiguration)\Package\PackageTmp\**\*.*"/>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Copy SourceFiles="@(PackagedFiles)" DestinationFiles="@(PackagedFiles->'c:\devDeploy\AOP\$(QAConfiguration)\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')"/>
</Target>
```